# My object in pygame dosen't move at an uniform speed

Tags: python, pygame

I was actually making a space invader game in pygame and I kept an image move at certain speed but when I run it I see that it moves at random speeds and stucks at times. It dosen't move at all sometimes if I am not pressing any keys.

```
enemyX_change = 5
enemyY_change = 40

def enemy(x,y):
    screen.blit(enemyImg,(x,y))


enemy(enemyX,enemyY)
```

Comment: Wonderful, but nobody can help you without more relevant code. It sounds like you're sticking things inside the event loop that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Make sure the updates are being called in a function that is being updated every frame, not in a function that only updates when something changes.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Where is the code that changes `enemyX` and `enemyY`?

Comment: The screen should update every frame, where the frame per second speed is set by you. Change the `self.movex` or `self.movey` that change the position of the sprite in the X and the Y axis respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the rest of your code but you could:
Place it in a while loop e.g.

```
enemyX_change = 5
enemyY_change = 40

def enemy(x,y):
    screen.blit(enemyImg,(x,y))

onRun = True
while onRun:
    enemyX += enemyX_change 
    enemyY += enemyY_change
    enemy((enemyX),(enemyY))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          runOn = False
```

But if you send me the rest of your code, I can better understand what you need within that loop.

Comment: Sorry, but this code doesn't do what you expect. You have to increment `enemyX` and `enemyY` continuously in the application loop e.g. `enemyX += enemyX_change`